# How to serve PHP together with Django?

Tags: php, python, django, .htaccess, fastcgi

i have a Bluehost hosting account, and i manually configure django with this [tutorial](http://alextreppass.co.uk/getting-django-working-on-bluehost), but now i need to run php scripts into a subdomain or in subfolder, how can i do that? my root .htaccess look like this

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
# For security reasons, Option followsymlinks cannot be overridden.
#Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(media/.*)$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(django\.fcgi/.*)$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ django.fcgi/$1 [L]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it, just change a little htaccess and ready, stay this way for those who have the same problem:

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5s .php
# For security reasons, Option followsymlinks cannot be overridden.
#Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(subfolder/.*)$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(media/.*)$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(django\.fcgi/.*)$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ django.fcgi/$1 [L]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It would actually be easier to serve from a subdomain, configured in its own [`VirtualHost`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#virtualhost) block.

Comment: thanks, but is not possible, because this is a shared hosting account.